# How to approach iOS Activity app "Awards" Control

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoa, apple-watch

I am trying to find approaches on building an iOS Control that looks much similar to "Activity" app "Awards 3D Control" on iOS.

Is there anything available around which is similar to this? Or How Should I approach this control? I need to develop it on both iOS app and for apple watch.

The snapshot of the same is attached below. You can flip it 360".

I am planning to do it with Native XCode Programming (Objective-C and/or Swift). Please suggest on the same lines.

[image]

Comment: you should check out the SceneKit: the "Award" is simply a 3D object you have to create.

Comment: Thank you @AndreyGershengoren What's the best approach to create a 3D object like this, I just have icons that will appear as a face of this 3D object, but How to create these one's so that they can be rotated 360" with touch.

Comment: you can create it in any 3D editor of your choice. here some more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48119378/which-format-file-for-3d-model-scenekit-arkit-better-to-use

Comment: if you don't need custom shape, volume etc. of the object you can simply a SCNNode and add a texture

Comment: Sorry to ask lame questions, So, I just need to google around SCNNode creation and adding textures to it? Thanks. @AndreyGershengoren

Comment: Still, not able to figure out yet. Seen a lot around the web, Does SCNNode needs to have a material (containing a texture)? Can you please share any sample or example? Thank you - @AndreyGershengoren

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194729/discussion-between-reno-jones-and-andrey-gershengoren).

Comment: @AndreyGershengoren which file format is good for iOS? Shall I just go with .obj 3d models for this? How about Android? Does .obj works best there? How about Min3D? Isn't it a good framework?